# Looping and ignoring flag - Python

Tags: python, loops

I am working on learning python and decided to write a small battle engine to use a few of the different items I have learned to make something a bit more complicated. The problem I am having is that I set a selection that the user makes that should cause one of either two parts to load, but instead it skips to my loop instead of performing the selection. Here is what I have so far:

```
import time
import random 
import sys

player_health = 100
enemy_health = random.randint(50, 110)

def monster_damage():
    mon_dmg = random.randint(5,25)
    enemy_health - mon_dmg
    print ('You hit the beast for ' + str(mon_dmg) + ' damage! Which brings its health to ' + str(enemy_health))
    player_dmg()

def player_dmg():
    pla_dmg = random.randint(5,15)
    player_health - pla_dmg
    print ('The beast strikes out for ' + str(pla_dmg) + ' damage to you. This leaves you with ' + str(player_health))

def run_away():
    run_chance = random.randint(1,10)
    if run_chance > 5:
        print ('You escape the beast!')
        time.sleep(10)
        sys.exit
    else:
        print ('You try to run and fail!')
        player_dmg()

def player_turn():
    print ('Your Turn:')
    print ('Your Health: ' + str(player_health) + ' Monsters Health: ' + str(enemy_health))
    print ('What is your next action?')
    print ('Please Select 1 to attack or 2 to run.')
    action = input()

    if action == 1:
        monster_damage()
    elif action == 2:
        run_away()

while player_health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
    player_turn()

if player_health <= 0:
    print ('The beast has vanquished you!')
    time.sleep(10)
    sys.exit
elif enemy_health <= 0:
    print ('You have vanquished the beast and saved our Chimichongas')
    time.sleep(10)
    sys.exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `input` returns a `str` not an `int`

```
action = input()
```

So this comparison will always return `False`

```
if action == 1:
```

For example

```
>>> '1' == 1
False
```

You can convert their input to an `int` as follows

```
action = int(input())
```

Comment: This assumes Python3.